# Backend is unable to find headers when sending request from IOS application

Tags: ios, swift, postman, alamofire, urlsession

i am able to hit api from postman, but when i hit from IOS application it always throws an error that "A valid API key is required to use this service."

**API Endpoint: https://connect.ttfnow.com/api/url/add 

Headers: key= "Authorization", value= "Token BDifVxMyHSlB" 

Method: POST

Body Raw Json: {url: "www.google.com"}**

I used postman code for swift but it did not worked in application.
I tried with url session and alamofire but nothing worked.

```
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Content-Type": "application/json",
                   "Authorization": "Token BDifVxMyHSlB"]
    
    let params: [String: Any] = ["url": "www.google.com"]
    AF.request(URL(string: "https://connect.ttfnow.com/api/url/add")!, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
        print(response)
    }
```

Here is code from url session

```
var semaphore = DispatchSemaphore (value: 0)

let parameters = "{\n    \"url\": \"www.google.com\"\n}"
let postData = parameters.data(using: .utf8)

var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://connect.ttfnow.com/api/url/add")!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
request.addValue("Token BDifVxMyHSlB", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("PHPSESSID=c6mirs7a3qspcq86hhdvo2o2po", forHTTPHeaderField: "Cookie")

request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = postData

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in 
     guard let data = data else {
       print(String(describing: error))
       semaphore.signal()
       return
     }
    print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
    semaphore.signal()
 }
```

task.resume()
semaphore.wait()

here is image from postman
[image]

Header tab of postman
[image]

Comment: A quick question, what kind of authentication is this API using?

Judging from the token you provided, it is neither a Basic or a JWT-based authentication.

Comment: in your postman image you have no Authorization. please send header tab image in postman.

Comment: @Ethenyl  i have attached image of header tab of postman.